# Scrolling sort order for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table that looks like:

```
 Users
---------------------
ID | LastName | FirstName

1  | Hane     | Aaron

2  | Messi    | Dennis

3  | Abraham  | Dont

4  | Abraham  | Carrey
```

If ordering by LastName, FirstName, the order I would expect for row numbers would be IDs: 4,3,1,2.

My problem is I select a row, and return it to the application. I would like to be able to then sort by that users ID to get the next row based on the same order.

So if I do the first select, and I return the ID of 4, I would like to be able to query sql to get the next user in order (3).

My attempted SQL statement would be

```
select TOP(1) RowNum, FirstName, LastName, ID
from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [LastName], [FirstName]) as RowNum
    from [Users]
) t
where t.RowNum > (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [LastName], [FirstName]) as RowNum
    from [Users]
    where ID = 4
)
```

but not only does this not work (the last sql statement will always return 1, because I'm obviously filtering the entire query down...) it seems like it's doing the same logic multiple times, and if I understand correctly order by will parse the entire table which would be pretty slow as the data set gets really large.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do efficiently (or at all?), I just want to scroll forward, and if possible wrap at the end (so ID 4,3,1,2,4,3,1,2 etc).

Thanks

Comment: I think what you envision is how excel does it, correct?

Comment: @scsimon I'm not quite sure what you mean by how excel does it, this is just an API, if I request "GetNextUser" and pass an ID of 4, I would like it to return the JSON for the user with ID of 3 in my example.

Comment: Then why the sorting on last name? Why not sort on ID?

Comment: You will have to have some mechanism in the calling application for storing the last value you selected and using it as a parameter in your sql statement.

Comment: @scsimon because ID is the generic ID created for a person. If I'm scrolling through a list of names, I would want them in alphabetical order, not just whatever person was added when

Comment: @TabAlleman that's what I meant by I would store the ID for the last selected user in the application, and then use that to request for the next ID returned from the query in order, if that makes sense. I request once, I store 4, then I send 4 to get 3, etc. I just can't figure out how to get the next one off the first without querying and ordering the entire table twice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [LastName], [FirstName]) as RowNum
    from [Users]
)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte
WHERE RowNum > (SELECT RowNum FROM cte WHERE ID=4)
ORDER BY RowNum ASC
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Only other question would be if there is a way to wrap if it doesn't exist (so you get to ID 2, but it's the last row_num, for it to go back to ID 4)

Comment: I'm sure it can be done with a modulo operation, but it will get pretty complicated.  You could also add an OR to the WHERE clause, and where no row exists with a row_num greater than that of the ID being passed, get row_num=1.

Comment: It's kind of gross, but I ended with

`DECLARE @currentId NUMERIC = 4;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LastName], [FirstName]) AS RowNum
    FROM [Users]
)
SELECT TOP 1 [Id], [FirstName], [LastName]
FROM cte
WHERE
 RowNum > (SELECT RowNum FROM cte WHERE ID=@currentId)
OR
 NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM cte
   WHERE
  RowNum > (SELECT RowNum FROM cte WHERE ID=@currentId))
ORDER BY RowNum ASC`

(I can't seem to figure out how to format in comments :()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having to make a call to the database each time you want the next user, why don't you make one call to the database to get `N` users (depending on how big your table is, this could be all the users or a subset). The application serving the API would then handle the cycling itself, rather than having to make multiple calls to the database to just get one record at a time.

Comment: The example was small, but it's multiple megabytes per stored user. However, mentioning it it would be possible JUST to save the ID's in a list and not the actual data, in say sets of 50 (they probably wouldn't scroll that much, and just paginate if they do get to the end), and then just request all of the data for the user when you actually scroll, that might work too.